# How to refresh div in order to get newly incoming data from DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the jquery news ticker from (http://jquerynewsticker.com/) as my footer. The footer is only loaded once, hence if I get new data to my DB, the new data won't show.

I want that the news ticker div is refreshed by itself every x seconds, so if there is new data in my DB, that it will be shown.

the news ticker is currently:

```
<div class="footer" id="footerticker">
    <ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden">
    <c:forEach items="${handcarryTicker}" var="handcarry2">
        <li class="news-item">
            <td>LGP: ${handcarry2.item1}</td>
            <td>${handcarry2.item2}</td>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I found several solutions for refreshing a div, but unfortunately, they did not work for me.
The footer is loaded and shown 3 seconds and then it disappears. How can I fix my code that it refreshes but not disappears?

My current script is:

```
<script>
    function refresh() {
        setInterval(() => {
            $('#footerticker').load(document.URL +  ' #footerticker')
        }, 3000);
    }
$(document).ready(refresh);
</script>
```

Comment: What is this magical `update` you are passing to `setInterval`?

Comment: Its a type, it should be `refresh´

Comment: I wonder what the recursion on this function looks like...

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to `setInterval` should be the function that you want to execute every 3000 milliseconds. In your example, `update` is not a defined function.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
<script>
    function refresh() {
        setInterval(() => {
            $('#footerticker').load(document.URL +  ' #footerticker')
        }, 3000);

    }
$(document).ready(refresh);
</script>
```

Comment: This worked a bit but not entirely. Now the footer is shown for 3000 milliseconds but after that it disappears and not showing again. Any idea why?

Comment: I suspect it's because `document.URL + ' #footerticker'` is not a valid URL. That expression is going to resolve to something like `http://myurl.com/ #footerticker`. Check your browser console to see if what errors are logged, if any.